# Gradle - Java - tests - java.lang.AssertionError Assertion Error

Tags: java, unit-testing, ant, junit, gradle

Running a gradle build.

Compile works fine but getting an error during :test task i.e. test(s) failed.

**Output is:**

```
com.tr.ids.biz.domain.TestAttributeDescriptorBeanProvider > testGetAttributeHandler FAILED
    java.lang.AssertionError at TestAttributeDescriptorBeanProvider.java:65

com.tr.ids.biz.domain.TestAttributeDescriptorBeanProvider > testGetSpringBeanWithExp FAILED
    java.lang.AssertionError at TestAttributeDescriptorBeanProvider.java:60




com.tr.ids.biz.domain.pvt.dao.TestRdbmsDAOFactory > testCreateDAO FAILED
    java.lang.AssertionError at TestRdbmsDAOFactory.java:90

83 tests completed, 3 failed
:test FAILED
```

If you see the first 2 failed tests, it's failing for Java fail() and the source code Java  file snapshot for those lines is (ignore the line# as i have used can -n command). Line # 60 and 65 are giving the error. I have tried joining line# 60+61+62 in one line as line#60, same error while gradle build:

-bash-3.2$ cat -n test/java/com/tr/ids/biz/domain/TestAttributeDescriptorBeanProvider.java | egrep "  *6[0-9]|70"

```
60                          fail(BASE_NAME + ": Failed in 'setUp()' method: "
61                                          + exp.getMessage()
62                                          + exp.getCause());
63                  } catch (SvcMockLibException exp) {
64
65                          fail(BASE_NAME + ": Failed in 'setUp()' method: "
66                                          + exp.getMessage()
67                                          + exp.getCause());
68                  }
69
70          }
```

-bash-3.2$

Similarly, 2nd file for line# 90 (showing lines 90,91,92 below) is failing and contains the following code:

```
assertEquals(
        "Test1: Returned bean is not instance of RdbmsAttributeDescriptorDAO",
        true, flag);
```

Any idea, why assertEquals() and fail () are failing.

The same source code when compiled with ANT, works and doesn't give these errors.

### ANT code performing the Unit testing part is:

```
  <!-- Execute the UNIT tests -->
  <target name="test-junit" depends="init,classpaths,classpath-junit,compile-junit" >
    <property name="test.junit.reports" value="junit-test-reports" />
    <delete dir="${test.junit.reports}" />
    <mkdir dir="${test.junit.reports}" />
    <mkdir dir="${test.junit.reports}/xml" />

    <junit printsummary="yes" haltonfailure="no" failureproperty="build.test.failure" >
      <batchtest todir="${test.junit.reports}/xml" >
        <fileset dir="${build.junit.classes}">
          <include name="**/Test*.class" />
        </fileset>
      </batchtest>
      <classpath>
        <pathelement path="${test-junit.classpath}" />
      </classpath>
      <formatter type="xml" />
    </junit>
    <junitreport todir="${test.junit.reports}" >
      <fileset dir="${test.junit.reports}/xml" >
        <include name="TEST*.xml" />
      </fileset>
      <report format="frames" todir="${test.junit.reports}/html" />
    </junitreport>

    <fail if="build.test.failure" message="*** JUnit test cases did not pass. ***" />
  </target>

  <!-- Setup classpath for JUnit tests -->
  <target name="classpath-junit" depends="init" >
    <property name="build.src.java-junit" value="${build.home}/test/java" />
    <property name="build.src.rsrc-junit" value="${build.home}/test/resources" />
    <property name="build.junit.classes"  value="${build.dest}/junit/classes" />
    <path id="test-junit.classpath">
    <path location="${build.junit.classes}" />
    <path location="${build.dest.classes}" />
    <path refid="build.classpath" />
    <path location="${build.src.conf}" />
    <path location="${build.home}" />
    <path location="${build.src.rsrc-junit}" />
    </path>
    <property name="test-junit.classpath" refid="test-junit.classpath" />
  </target>

  <!-- Compile the JUnit source code -->
  <target name="compile-junit" depends="init,classpaths,classpath-junit,compile" >
    <delete dir="${build.junit.classes}"/>
    <mkdir dir="${build.junit.classes}"/>
    <javac
       destdir="${build.junit.classes}"
       debug="true"
       debuglevel="lines,vars,source"
       optimize="false"
       deprecation="${build.compiler.deprecation}">
       <classpath>
          <path refid="build.classpath" />
          <path refid="test-junit.classpath" />
       </classpath>
       <src path="${build.src.java-junit}"/>
    </javac>
  </target>
```

**Note**: When I tried ANT based target for another project, both ANT / Gradle failed at the unit tests thus, ANT code does fail the tests for some projects which fail in Gradle as well. But the case I have given above runs fine in ANT and fails in Gradle "gradle clean build" step (where build also calls :test task).

Comment: The tests are failing, because they reach the fail method and flag seems to be false. Can you show us the unit test part of your build.xml file, because the Ant build should fail, too.

Comment: Included ANT code in the original post. thanks.

Comment: seems like error line# 65,60 is gone after I added asm jars or xerces jar as dependency for tests